# Question about identification for this parametrization

Tags: regression, estimation, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, identifiability

Assume I observe a poisson-process with a rate $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$.

I would like to model $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$ as:

$\boldsymbol{\lambda} = \boldsymbol{\pi}_1\boldsymbol{\lambda}_1 + \boldsymbol{\pi}_2\boldsymbol{\lambda}_2$

where

$\boldsymbol{\pi}_k = \text{exp}(\boldsymbol{1}\beta_{1k} + \boldsymbol{a}_1\beta_{2k})$ for $k=1,2$

$\boldsymbol{\lambda}_k = \text{exp}(\boldsymbol{1}\gamma_{1k} + \boldsymbol{b}_1\gamma_{2k})$ for $k=1,2$

and $\boldsymbol{a}_1 \ne \boldsymbol{b}_1$.

**My question is:**

Why are the parameters from this model not identifiable? I know the *identification-problem* from the estimation of simulteous-equation-problems where, for instance, each equation contains all the aviable information.

To express the Problem I would need to rewrite my $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$ equation such that I can show that my parameters collapse into some other parameter right? Like:

$\boldsymbol{\lambda} = \text{exp}(\boldsymbol{1}\beta_{11} + \boldsymbol{a}_1\beta_{21})\text{exp}(\boldsymbol{1}\gamma_{11} + \boldsymbol{b}_1\gamma_{21}) + \text{exp}(\boldsymbol{1}\beta_{12} + \boldsymbol{a}_1\beta_{22})\text{exp}(\boldsymbol{1}\gamma_{12} + \boldsymbol{b}_1\gamma_{22})$

$\boldsymbol{\lambda} = \text{exp}(\boldsymbol{1}\underbrace{(\beta_{11} + \gamma_{11})}_{\theta_{11}} + \boldsymbol{a}_1\beta_{21} + \boldsymbol{b}_1\gamma_{21}) + \text{exp}(\boldsymbol{1}\underbrace{(\beta_{12} + \gamma_{12})}_{\theta_{12}} + \boldsymbol{a}_1\beta_{22} + \boldsymbol{b}_1\gamma_{22})$

$\boldsymbol{\lambda} = \text{exp}(\boldsymbol{1}\theta_{11} + \boldsymbol{a}_1\beta_{21} + \boldsymbol{b}_1\gamma_{21}) + \text{exp}(\boldsymbol{1}\theta_{12} + \boldsymbol{a}_1\beta_{22} + \boldsymbol{b}_1\gamma_{22})$

So, to identify those parameters, I would actually need to fix either $\beta_{1k}$ or $\gamma_{1k}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider

$\lambda =\pi_1\lambda_1 + \pi_2\lambda_2$

where

$\pi_1 = \exp(1\beta_{11} + a_1\beta_{21})$
$\pi_2 = \exp(1\beta_{12} + a_1\beta_{22})$

So $\lambda =\exp(\beta_{11}) \exp(a_1\beta_{21})\lambda_1 + \exp(\beta_{12}) \exp(a_1\beta_{22})\lambda_2$, or

$\lambda =\exp(a_1\beta_{21})[\exp(\beta_{11}) \lambda_1] + \exp(a_1\beta_{22})[\exp(\beta_{12}) \lambda_2]$

Clearly $[\exp(\beta_{11}) \lambda_1]$ isn't identifiable, since we only see the product; you can multiply one by $c$ and the other by $1/c$ without changing anything. Similarly for $[\exp(\beta_{12}) \lambda_2]$.

You have a similar issue with the $\gamma$'s. So it's more of a problem, perhaps, than you thought.

Comment: So even if I would fix all the intercept-values, i.e., I fix $\beta_{1k}$ and $\gamma_{1k}$ to be some number, the equation would still not be identifiable since I can do the "c-thing" with the product of $\text{exp}(\boldsymbol{a}_1\beta_{2k})\lambda_k$ too?

Comment: Unless I missed something (and I could easily have, I didn't check everything carefully), I think fixing both $β_{1k}$ and $γ_{1k}$ should work.

Comment: Hm ok. I dont quite get why the same problem cannot occur for $\text{exp}(\boldsymbol{a}_1\beta_{2k})\boldsymbol{\lambda_k}$?

Comment: Because $a_1$ occurs in another term.

Comment: Is identification acieved if I summarize the intercept terms $\beta_{1k} + \alpha_{1k} = \theta_k$ and estimate this parametrization? My guess is yes since I cannot do the c-thing. Though I get an estimate of the summarized intercept value $\theta_k$ I'm really interested in the slope values this should be applicable?